# Filter options by prior field choices

Tags: cognito-forms

We are building applications forms for volunteers.  We have offices all over the country so our list is growing larger.  I want to reduce those office options when a potential applicant selects their State.  Eg. If "Select you state" = OH, then only show "Cleveland, & Cincinnati".

Currently when they select the city and the applicant submits the form it is emailed to the representative at that office.

So, do I create a two separate Choice Fields one for state and the other for city and how do I build the conditional logic so that the email submission goes out properly?

Answer (score 1):

The following blog post describes how to implement cascading choices in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

http://blog.cognitoforms.com/how-to-implement-cascading-choices-in-cognito-forms

In terms of how to route the email notifications, you can create notification emails for each office, specify the appropriate representative email addresses, and use conditional logic to only send the email when the corresponding office is selected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I go that section figured out.  My greatest challenge is how do I filter/limit options based on a previous selection.  So, I have a section listed with states and then I want to be able to narrow options down based on the state selected.  Select Ohio then only offices/cities in ohio appear.

Comment: @TomCsora The blog post I mentioned first describes one way to do this.  You would need separate conditionally visible Choice fields for each state, but the approach works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to "filter" choice fields based on another field yet. But there is a work around that you can do.

You can setup additional choice fields for each state, each state specific choice field would then include the Office / City names associated to that state. Then when a state is selected the related choice field can be shown.

In my example below I setup both Ohio and Oregon in the "Select Your State" choice field and then added a choice field with cities for both Ohio and Oregon.

[image]

When the user goes to select a state the form only shows the offices for the selected state as you can see below:

[image]

To setup the office choice fields to show and hide you setup "Show This Field" to show when the specific state is selected.

[image]